# CSS goes back to default on Chrome dev tools

Tags: css, google-chrome

i'm using MAMP on OSx mountain Lion.

while working on a site hosted in localhost suddenly, when i try to edit the CSS in the chrome developer tools it goes back back to default.

example:

if i change **border: 0px** to **border: 1px** it goes back to **0px**.

this happens only in the site on localhost.

any help would be appreciated...

Thanks!

Comment: Are you refereshing the page after editing?

Comment: what version of chrome do you use? I remember such issue on older versions

Comment: i'm using Chrome Version 22.0.1229.79, and of course i'm not refreshing the page... this is so annoying !!

Comment: I am using the same version of chrome with MAMP 2.0.5 on Snow Leopard and am not experiencing this. Instead of editing the CSS have you tried editing the HTML side and added an inline-style to the element? That would override the CSS and possibly be a workaround for you...

Comment: Have you tried firebug, if yes do you get the same result there?

Comment: Same problem when I work on sites on a local network. Never had this issue until I upgraded to Mountain Lion. Sometimes clearing the cookies/cache tends to help, but it varies. I ended up using Chrome Canary for web dev on local sites, it doesn't seem to have the same issue.

Comment: MAMP should have nothing to do with editing CSS styles, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check your CSS using a tool like [CSSLint](http://csslint.net). It seems that the latest builds of Chrome won't let you edit CSS in the Developer Tools that appear after a syntax error in your CSS.